# Import HTML into Google Spreadsheet, programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm developing a Google Script to import an HTML file into a new Spreadsheet.
To do so, my script works like that :

1. initialize an upload form
2. save the new file into Google Drive, in a public folder.
3. create a new spreadsheet
4. set a formula into the first cell : `=IMPORTHTML`, to import the html file, via the googledrive public URL (FYI, it only works with a public folder)
5. Here is my issue : I'd like to unlink the new spreadsheet from the html file, in order to be able to remove the HTML file, for security reason. To do so, I tried to :

   - copy the values and paste them with `contentsOnly=true` option, to a new sheet => ERROR
   - add a "Utilities.sleep" before that to be sure the HTML is well imported (just for paranoia, it doesn't change anything...)

It works only if I copy and paste without `contentsOnly=true`.

Here is my script : https://script.google.com/d/1NH3S3-TT-Yq43gqN4gkVwyTfhm9ZLz6aDVEB_w6gvvjFd3Xwdn0b0-Cg/edit?usp=sharing

Try this script removing the `{contentsOnly:true}` on line 58, it should work.
If you leave it, it generates this error : "An error occurred on the server(...)"

Could you help me ?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another way to do my copy :

I replaced

```
sourceAllData.copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
```

by :

```
sheet2.getRange(sourceAllData.getA1Notation()).setValues(sourceAllData.getValues());
```